# Win7 Path not being recongized

Tags: windows-7, environment-variables

I have this path

```
PATH=%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\
```

But when I open a cmd prompt, it won't run simple commands that are located in the Windows\system32 directory such as ipconfg, ping, etc.

Any ideas as to why or how to fix this stupid thing so I don't have to navigate to that directory everytime.

Comment: What happens if you use start > Run > c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe and then enter the command you want?  (I'm asking because cmd.exe sometimes gets hijacked etc.)

Comment: And what does `set path` give you?

Comment: @Debra it says command can't be found.

Comment: @Rik, It shows the path I posted in my question, duh.

Comment: Strange. For me its showing `Path=C:\Windows\system32;....` etc. and not `PATH=%SystemRoot%\system32;...` etc. (%System% is substituted in my path. It only shows %SystemRoot% in my environment dialog-settings. Not at a command prompt)

Comment: OK, with apologies, your Windows install is probably just not at C:\Windows\system32.  Please type in "echo %systemroot% and note the path shown. That's where your Windows install is, but it may be opening cmd.exe from another (restricted) location.  Is there any chance that you have more than one Windows install?

Comment: @Debra, it is c:\Windows and only one installation of Windows 7 on this machine.

Comment: Does "echo %systemroo%" display C:\Windows? Sorry, I'm just not sure if you're stating where the install is, or the result of the command.  If so, use Windows Explorer & go to C:\Windows\system32, and note the details about the file "cmd.exe", if it's there.  Is it possible that you, or something in some other way, moved the location of "cmd.exe"?  If so, search for "cmd.exe" and see if it's found somewhere else. (Be sure to enable display of hidden files & folders first!) I'm asking because some companies (re)move cmd.exe as a sort of blunt "security".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that when you type `set path` in a command prompt the path also contains `PATH=%systemroot%\system32`. If this is the case your `%systemroot%` does not get expanded to `C:\Windows` when starting `cmd.exe`.

You can check your registry in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment`. All the names containing values with `%` characters (e.g. `windir`, `temp`, `path` and `comspec`) **should be** of type `REG_EXPAND_SZ` (and **not** `REG_SZ`) or the variable won't be expanded.

Comment: I checked and these are all correct but it still doesn't expand the variables when I use set path.

Comment: If, however, I use echo %systemroot%, it shows c:\windows

Comment: This is strange. (I was almost certain that was it). Could you check the following: Is `HKCU\Environment\Path` (user-path) also of `REG_EXPAND_SZ`? Does that one contain unexpanded `%`-variables? Could you check the environment setting in Computer properties. They should not display `%systemroot%` in the list. Only when editing they should give `%systemroot%`.

Comment: You could of course type the path in the variables dialog complete with `C:\Windows` instead of `%systemroot%` but that's just a workaround. BTW if my previous comment (about user-path) did not help could you type the **first** path in your complete path with `C:\Windows`. I read somewhere if the first character is `%` this could be a problem. It seems unlikely but easy to try.

Comment: What is funny is that if I go to the Environment Variables window in CP, it shows c:\windows; .... not c:\%systemroot%; ...

Comment: That's the way it should be. In the window it shows the expanded version. Only if you going to change it gives it the `%systemroot%`. Internally it still has the `%systemroot%`. Try changing the values. (and set the first `%systemroot%` to `C:\Windows`. Did you already check the `HKCU\Environment\Path`. BTW You know there is a user-path and a system-path? They are joint together when you open a cmd.exe.

Comment: I modified the HKCU\Environment\Path value to NOT have the variables and it still showed it when I type set path.

Comment: Are you sure the `%` in `set path` are from your **user**-path and not from the **system**-path. You could also change all the `%` in the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\Path`. So there are no `%` in both paths.

Comment: Pardon me, it was the HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\Path value that I modified.

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing ; from the end of the last entry, other than that it looks ok.

Try adding paths in one at a time until you get to the point it no longer behaves the way you expect.